# Is there a term for an animal with 4 arms and 2 legs?

Tags: terms-of-venery

[image]I have an Adoptable business, and I've started creating anthropomorphic animals with 4 arms, 2 legs. Is there a term for this type of animal?

Comment: which is it?.2 arms 4 legs or 4 arms 2 legs? A centaur has two arms four legs.

Comment: The animal has 4 arms 2 legs.

Comment: Vishnu fits except for the being an animal part.

Answer (score 7):

**Tetrabrachius** is a medical term for a person born with four arms (apparently it can happen from incomplete twinning) or for a four-armed monster. It's just Latin for four-armed, so I think it would work for you. You could specify a bipedal tetrabrachius or a tetrabrachial biped if you want to stress the two legs, but I don't think you need it. See http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/tetrabrachius